# Can someone tell me what Regex would match this?

Tags: regex, string

I'm trying to make a regex that would match this string:

```
asf, Algeria, Wilaya d' El Tarf,
```

So pretty much: (word-with-characters){,}{space}  and repeat 3 times (no more, no less).

I tried this:

```
 ^([\w ']+[,]?){3}$
```

But I can't seem to get the "no more, no less part" (this just matches anything with words, separated by commas and spaces, like "asf, Algeria").

I'm very new to Regex so sorry for my noobness.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make the comma mandatory:

```
^([\w ']+,){3}$
```

Otherwise `"asf, Algeria"` can be split into exactly three matching groups like so:

1. `"asf,"`
2. `" Algeri"`
3. `"a"`

Making the comma mandatory closes that loophole.

Comment: Ohhhhh. I knew I was doing something wrong with the comma. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's better to use ^([^,]+, *){3}$ , depends on what characters are allowed.